# Multiple else If statements for NSURL SKSpriteNode buttons - 2 out of 6 don't open?

Tags: ios, swift

I simply cannot see why the Facebook and Twitter buttons aren't opening on touch?

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)


// Reviews & Rating
        let reviewsAppString = "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=APP_ID"
        let reviewsApp = NSURL(string: reviewsAppString)
        let reviewsWebString = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/DEVELOPER_NAME/DEVELOPER_ID"
        let reviewsWeb = NSURL(string: reviewsWebString)

// Facebook
        let fbWebString = "https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME"
        let fbWeb = NSURL(string: fbWebString)
        let fbAppString = "fb://profile/PAGE_ID"
        let fbApp = NSURL(string: fbAppString)
// Twitter
        let twWebString = "https://twitter.com/USER_NAME"
        let twWeb = NSURL(string: twWebString)
        let twAppString = "twitter://user?screen_name=USER_ID"
        let twApp = NSURL(string: twAppString)



        if nodeAtPoint(location) == gameCenterButton {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showLeaderboard", object: nil)
        }
        else if nodeAtPoint(location) == playButton {
            presentScene(GameScene())
        }
        else if nodeAtPoint(location) == soundButton {
            toggleSound()
        }

// REVIEWS AND RATINGS
        else if nodeAtPoint(location) == rateButton {
            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(reviewsApp!)) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(reviewsApp!)
        }
            else {
            if  UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(reviewsWeb!)   {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(reviewsWeb!)
            }
// FACEBOOK
        else if nodeAtPoint(location) == facebookButton {
            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(fbApp!)) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fbApp!)
            }
            else {
            if  UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(fbWeb!)   {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fbWeb!)
                }
 // TWITTER
        else if nodeAtPoint(location) == twitterButton {
            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(twApp!)) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(twApp!)
            }
            else {
                if  UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(twWeb!)   {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(twWeb!)
                }
```

I can only think that i am using too many else if statements and there is a better/cleaner way to do it, but i'm stumped!

**Xcode 7.3.1 - Swift 2.2**

Comment: Have you stepped through the if statement with the debugger?

Comment: No, i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: This link should help, using a breakpoint to step over each line of code should make this an easy problem to diagnose: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingtheDebugger.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH57-SW1l

Comment: I named the Image the same as the Call ... Appreciate your help!

Comment: It look like i spoke too soon ... The problem persists! I'm going the documentation you linked and trying to debug ... any other advice on what I should be looking for?

Comment: PARTIALLY RESOLVED: I had to add fb twitter http https to the info.plist in order for them to open 3rd party apps/links ... 
**NOTE: Edit the info.plist as a Property List NOT Source Code**

**REMAINING PROBLEM:** only 4 of the 6 buttons work in the order they are listed above in my code. I moved some around and the top 4 worked. Is touches or else if limited to 4 statements/calls? 
Apologies for incorrect terminology.

Comment: Can anyone give an update to this please?